# Combine two date fields in tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm using Tableau Software and I connected it with Salesforce. I created a calculated field to calculate a ratio of two values from two different columns, and I want to show the evolution of this ratio. The problem is that the two values are linked with two different columns from two different tables. How can I merge the two dates columns ?

Thank you for your help .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the two date fields as keys in the [join/relationship](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/joining_tables.htm)/[blend](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multiple_connections.htm) between the two tables. Then you can use one of the date fields to create the line chart. Does it make sense?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).